# Excel formula to increase month by one and week in month by one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to increase the week in month by one as well as increase the month by one.

Basically I need an ongoing list of Mondays that would follow this pattern:

```
Month 1 2016, Week 1 2016, Monday = 4th Jan 2016
Month 2 2016, Week 2 2016, Monday = 8th Feb 2016
Month 3 2016, Week 3 2016, Monday = 21st Mar 2016
Month 4 2016, Week 4 2016, Monday = 25th Apr 2016
Month 5 2016, Week 1 2016, Monday = 2nd May 2016
Month 6 2016, Week 2 2016, Monday = 13th Jun 2016
```

Comment: Can you explain that how will you use this solution and where to use? You just say what you want to do and don't say that where can get the inputted value? I means, I think that you requirement cannot do with an excel formula, but it can do with excel-vba. So, explain more about where to use? And you should try something and should post yours. For getting this result, we need to input month and year if want to do with excel-vba.

Comment: @NaingWinHtun It can be done with an Excel formula. It is just a bit lengthy (see my solution below).

Comment: @Paul , why don't you  count 5th Monday in May, 2016? that is 30th May, 2016

Comment: @Ralph I suggest you to read the question carefully. Your answer is not meet the requirement. Note, I see your answer and I already tested it.

Comment: @pcw, because I missed that one, but you are right, I would want to have the Monday of the 5th week of may.  Good spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as below

```
month   date_of_first_Monday                         how_many_Mondays                                               Ith_Monday_request                       the_date_request
1/1     =Choose(Weekday(A2,2),0,6,5,4,3,2,1)+A2      =roundup((day(eomonth(a2,0))-weekday(eomonth(a2,0),3))/7,0)    =if(month(a2)=1,1,if(d1+1>c2,1,d1+1))    =b2+7*(d2-1)
2/1        
3/1
```

[image]

Comment: you have met your objective.  Is this part one of the solution?

Comment: it could be.  But I have dish to wash.

Comment: I look forward to your dishes being clean.

Comment: You're Excel game is very strong.  Thank you PCW.